# DDD: Eventual consistency and 1 to n relationships

Tags: domain-driven-design

In my domain I have Product and Order aggregates. Orders reference Products. This is a 1 to n relationship, so a Product has many Orders and Orders belong to a Product. When a Product is discontinued a ProductDiscontinued event is published and all Orders that belong to that Product must be cancelled. So there's an adapter that receives the ProductDiscontinued event via RabbitMQ. The adapter then delegates cancelling Orders to an application service. How can I achieve that a single Order is cancelled in a single transaction? Should the adapter iterate all Orders of the discontinued Product and call the application service for every single Order? Should I just ignore that I modify more than one aggregate in a single transaction and call the application service just once with a list of all affected OrderIds? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Do you use CQRS?

Comment: No, we don't use CQRS.

Comment: From what I understood you have an event that modify 'n' aggregates. They should be modified in different transactions (commands) because they are different aggregates.
The tricker part of this can be manage a failing command, you have to ask yourself what you want to happen if you have to modify 5 aggregates and the second fail? Do you need to assure that all the aggregates are modified? Can you reprocess the event in the case of failure (are the changes on the aggregates idempotent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the DDD point of view, the Aggregate is the transaction boundary. The transaction *should* not be larger than the Aggregate. This rule exist in order to force one to correctly design the Aggregates, to not depend on multiple Aggregates modified in the same transaction.

However, you already designed your Aggregates having that in mind (from what I can see).

> Should the adapter iterate all Orders of the discontinued Product and call the application service for every single Order?

This is the *normal* way of doing things.

> Should I just ignore that I modify more than one aggregate in a single transaction and call the application service just once with a list of all affected OrderIds?

In the context of what I wrote earlier, you *may* do that if somehow it offers a better performance (I don't see how a bigger transaction can give better performance but hey, it depends on the code also).